# Symfony2 is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') during 404 error page display, causing ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: twig, symfony-2.1

I have setup custom error pages to display for certain HTTP errors in the folder:

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/
```

The 403 page (`error403.html.twig`) works and displays as expected.

The 500 page (`error500.html.twig`) works and displays as expected.

The 404 page (`error404.html.twig`) throws a 500 server error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException'

The error is being thrown by doing an auth check to display certain menu items for users that are or aren't authenticated:

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %}
```

If I remove that check and just allow all menu items to display, the page loads the error page as expected. Again, the 403 page displays as it should and utilizes the auth checks without a problem.

I'm stuck on this one. The pages are EXACTLY the same, apart from the filename.

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: The latest and greatest. 2.1-dev I believe

Comment: I think it would be better (because of the -dev version) to create an issue on github, symfony guys are really helpful there :)

Comment: Added to GitHub: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5225

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use the `is_granted` in a 404 page since 2.1:

It's mentioned in the upgrade file

> The Firewall listener is now registered after the Router listener. This means that specific Firewall URLs (like /login_check and /logout) must now have proper routes defined in your routing configuration. Also, if you have a custom 404 error page, make sure that you do not use any security related features such as `is_granted` on it.

See: 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md#security

Comment: Yes, they added it to the documentation after having received multiple issue posts on GitHub... I'm still not a huge fan of how this is handled.

Comment: [Symfony 2.8 catches the exception, and instead will return false](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/15953). So no more error, but may not quite be the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 15):

If symfony < 2.8 :

```
{% if app.user is not null and is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
```

See : https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/2078

Edit from Dec 17 '15:

This is no longer needed since 2.8,

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
```

works fine now.

source: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-dx-improvements#allow-to-check-for-security-even-in-pages-not-covered-by-firewalls

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking for `app.security.token` to be more strict and evaluate to `true` even when user is anonymous.

If you check for `app.user` it will evaluate `false` in Exception templates, but even when the firewall **is** present (= regular templates) but the user is not logged. This will prevent - for example - the display of a login button.

See: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/2359