# Symfony2 - Custom error pages are never shown

Tags: symfony, custom-error-pages

I'm trying to customize the error.html.twig, error403.html.twig, error404.html.twig and error500.html.twig, so far i've tried to get the error403.html.twig error caused by an a AccessDeniedExceptionw which is a 403 forbidden, but it displays the custom error page. I created the templates inside app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception like it says [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) but so far, no luck.

All the templates extend the website base template

403:

```
    {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<div id="header">
    <a href="{{path ('login')}}" class="fl"><img src="{{ asset('images/access_error.png') }}" alt="TiCad" /></a>
    <div class="fr"><h1>HA OCURRIDO UN ERROR:</h1></div>
    <div align="center">No posee permisos suficientes para acceder a esta seccion, si desea ingresar con otra cuenta haga clic <a href="{{path ('login')}}">AQUI</a></div>
{% endblock %}
```

404:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<div id="header">
    <a href="{{path ('login')}}" class="fl"><img src="{{ asset('images/error404.png') }}" alt="TiCad" /></a>
    <div class="fr"><h1>HA OCURRIDO UN ERROR:</h1></div>
    <div align="center">No encontrado. Por favor, intente de nuevo.</div>
{% endblock %}
```

500:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
        <h1><img src="{{ asset('images/internal_server.png') }}" alt="Monse" />Oops! Ha ocurrido un error</h1>
        <h2>Error interno en el servidor</h2>


        <div>
            Algo no funciona. Por favor, Háznos saber que estabas haciendo cuando ocurrio este error, envia un email a <a href="mailto:ticad@icad.com.ve">ticad@icad.com.ve</a>
            Lo arreglaremos lo mas pronto posible. iCad Diseno Inteligente, C.A. se disculpa por los inconvenientes causados. 
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom templates won't show in your dev. environment. You can test them using production environment, just make sure to clear the cache.

Comment: I realized this about a month ago or so. I never did back then, yet I never answered the question (I didn't remember it didn't had a concrete answer), yet, the correct answer is yours (I was working on the DEV enviroment back then)

Comment: Read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#the-default-exceptioncontroller `Testing Error Pages during Development`

Answer (score 1):

It will throw an error on this line: {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

You can check your webserver logs; possibly your symfony logs too for the error.

See also:

- [Symfony2 error 500 instead of 404 at production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426899/symfony2-error-500-instead-of-404-at-production)
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5206
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/symfony2/YFeSKgWn4RA

I'm also trying to display the error message within the layout i already have, with no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have yo cleared the cache?
Also, could you give us the names of your error files?

Comment: Hi! Yes, i've cleared the cache. and the names of the files are on top (error.html.twig, error403.html.twig, error404.html.twig and error500.html.twig)