# How to add custom error page Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, exception, error-handling

I have tried as [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller/error_pages.html) says:

```
app/
└─ Resources/
   └─ TwigBundle/
      └─ views/
         └─ Exception/
            ├─ error404.html.twig
            ├─ error403.html.twig
            ├─ error.html.twig      # All other HTML errors (including 500)
            ├─ error404.json.twig
            ├─ error403.json.twig
            └─ error.json.twig      # All other JSON errors (including 500)
```

But none of those shows the custom page on prod env. Then I tried to add in the same `Exception` folder a `exception.html.twig` file and it work for all the errors (404, 500, ...), but it shows it in dev, so I can't see the error when developing if I have that file. And inside the production env it shows always the red screen

[image]

So what's the proper way to make a custom error page to production and how to test it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - Custom error pages are never shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621663/symfony2-custom-error-pages-are-never-shown)

Comment: Symfony 3 not works as Symfony 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error pages are not used in development environment. During development, it shows an other error page with more debug information (which may contain information you don't want to expose public). The Symfony header bar is not showed in production by default.

To see how the error pages look like in production, try [Error page previews](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-error-page-previews):

```
# app/config/routing_dev.yml
_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error
```

If your production environment shows the Symfony Exception page, make sure the `debug` flag is set to false in `app.php`:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

Comment: Thanks but that not answer the question. In my production server it's not showing the common 404 page, it shows the red page of symfony. Maybe the production enviroment is not aswering as production?

Comment: I've updated my question. If that doesn't help, please share some information from `config_prod.yml` and (if you changed something) your `app.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer for your question is about clear cache. 
use this command : 
***$php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod*** 
and you will get your Error pages,  
Good luck.