# Symfony throwing ResourceNotFoundException with overridden error templates

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing

I have a small problem. I have already overridden the templates in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/` and have error, error404 and error500.html.twig respectively. **I have deleted the cache** and upon going on a undefined page I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException' in E:\svn\medapp\app\cache\prod\appProdUrlMatcher.php:4044 Stack trace: #0 E:\svn\medapp\app\cache\prod\classes.php(1433): appProdUrlMatcher->match('/asdasd') #1 E:\svn\medapp\app\cache\prod\classes.php(19616): Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #2 E:\svn\medapp\app\cache\prod\classes.php(2583): JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\Router\I18nRouter->matchRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) #3 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) #4 E:\svn\medapp\app\cache\prod\classes.php(2352): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDis in E:\svn\medapp\app\cache\prod\classes.php on line 5334
>   503 Service Unavailable

The prod.log:

> [2016-02-26 09:40:49] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET /asdasdas"" at
>   E:\svn\medapp\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php
>   line 176 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code:
>   0): No route found for \"GET /asdasdas\" at
>   E:\svn\medapp\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php:176,
>   Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code:
>   0):  at
>   E:\svn\medapp\app\cache\prod\appProdUrlMatcher.php:4044)"} []
>   [2016-02-26 09:40:49] request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling
>   an exception (Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during
>   the rendering of a template ("The token storage contains no
>   authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no
>   firewall configured for this URL.") in
>   "MedAppBundle:Default:base.html.twig" at line 95. at
>   E:\svn\medapp\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php line 182)
>   {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Runtime(code: 0): An exception has
>   been thrown during the rendering of a template (\"The token storage
>   contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that
>   there is no firewall configured for this URL.\") in
>   \"MedAppBundle:Default:base.html.twig\" at line 95. at
>   E:\svn\medapp\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php:182,
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code:
>   0): The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible
>   reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at
>   E:\svn\medapp\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker.php:57)"}
>   [] [2016-02-26 09:40:49] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering
>   of a template ("The token storage contains no authentication token.
>   One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for
>   this URL.") in "MedAppBundle:Default:base.html.twig" at line 95." at
>   E:\svn\medapp\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php line 182
>   {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Runtime(code: 0): An exception has
>   been thrown during the rendering of a template (\"The token storage
>   contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that
>   there is no firewall configured for this URL.\") in
>   \"MedAppBundle:Default:base.html.twig\" at line 95. at
>   E:\svn\medapp\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php:182,
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code:
>   0): The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible
>   reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at
>   E:\svn\medapp\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker.php:57,
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code:
>   0): No route found for \"GET /asdasdas\" at
>   E:\svn\medapp\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php:176,
>   Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code:
>   0):  at
>   E:\svn\medapp\app\cache\prod\appProdUrlMatcher.php:4044)"} []
>   [2016-02-26 09:40:49] request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling
>   an exception (Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during
>   the rendering of a template ("The token storage contains no
>   authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no
>   firewall configured for this URL.") in
>   "MedAppBundle:Default:base.html.twig" at line 95. at
>   E:\svn\medapp\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php line 182)
>   {"exception":"[object] (Twig_Error_Runtime(code: 0): An exception has
>   been thrown during the rendering of a template (\"The token storage
>   contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that
>   there is no firewall configured for this URL.\") in
>   \"MedAppBundle:Default:base.html.twig\" at line 95. at
>   E:\svn\medapp\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php:182,
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException(code:
>   0): The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible
>   reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL. at
>   E:\svn\medapp\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker.php:57)"}
>   []

If I delete or rename the TwigBundle templates and then delete the cache, I get the standard Symfony error page:

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>
> The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>
> Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have `503 Service Unavailable`. Try to create `error.html.twig` tempalte for non **404** and **500** errors.

Comment: I had that already. It seems that if I delete everything except that one and clear the cache it works. I'll look more into it.

Comment: Ok. Try to enable debug mode for prod environment - there should be more detailed error trace.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426899/symfony2-error-500-instead-of-404-at-production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, sorry for the bother.

The problem was the error templates were calling parent() for the templates they are extending

```
{% extends 'MedAppBundle:Default:base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <div class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 error-content" >
                <h1 class="error-title">404</h1>

                <h2 class="error-header2">Resource Not Found
                </h2>

                <p>The resource requested could not be found on this server!</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

And in the parent template I was asking for the token storage.

Something good to learn for the future.